# Android Studio: Back Button for previous Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I've created an `Activity` with a `Navigation Drawer` and replaced the options icon (placed in the top-right corner) with an `ImageButton` to handle the back click.

The problem is, that I don't know how to do it. I'm a little confused about how to use the back button. What code should I do to go to the previous `Activity`?

A back button for:
Activity to Another Activity and MainActivity to Fragment activity.

this is my **Manifest code:**

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.activity.Accomodation"
        android:label="Accomodation"
        android:parentActivityName="com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.activity.SpecialPage">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.activity.SpecialPage" />
    </activity>
```

this is my **Accommodation activity:**

```
package com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.R;


public class Accomodation extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accomodation);
  } }
```

and this is my **SpecialPage code:** which will be the parent activity.

```
package com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.activity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import com.teamamazing.with_sidebar.R;


public class SpecialPage extends AppCompatActivity {

public ImageButton accomodation;


public void init() {
    accomodation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.AccomodationButton);
    accomodation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent accomodation = new Intent(SpecialPage.this, Accomodation.class);

            startActivity(accomodation);


        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_special_page);

    init();
}}
```

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: you can start a new instance of the *previous* activity, or `finish()` current activity to go to previous, if it is not finished yet.

Comment: My two cents here, why do you need a back button? Android handles the activity stack very good itself in back-terms. edit: If you need a back arrow(button), place it in the top LEFT corner, to take into account the material design guide lines.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re I have Navigation Drawer icon on the left corner, so I don't know where I'm going to place the back button. XD

Comment: changed my mind: if you are inside of a fragment, then override the onBackPressed method of the activity and handle the fragment cycle yourself.

Comment: Please select the correct answer, which solved your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **onBackPressed()** or **finish()** Method.

```
  buttonClickOBJ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

       onBackPressed();

    }
});
```

**[onBackPressed ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())**

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Comment: Where this code should be placed? If I'm not wrong, is it in the Accomodation.java? Thanks

Comment: @AlyzaMarieIgnacio `Where this code should be placed?` .Mine question is where you want ?

Comment: Place it inside of your activity or your fragment, which calls it on the activity.

Comment: but the setOnClickListener doesn't working.
Sorry, but please help me. (^^)"

Comment: @AlyzaMarieIgnacio `setOnClickListener ` is demo . Please tell us where you want

Comment: U can use your accomodation button onClickListener. And maybe rename the resource name to make it start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: home is the layout where you want to go back

Answer (score 1):

Easy way

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setMessage("If You Enjoy The App Please Rate us?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent play =
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kd.travellingtips"));
                    startActivity(play);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Add the Listener to the button you want to associate with it. Then initiate a back-press option within the method.

Comment: Obviously copied from IntelliJ Amiya's answers. edit: and yeah, wrong,too.

Comment: Still, which information does this answer add to Amiyas answer?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, then please mark it as the correct answer. Although I suggest to choose IntelliJ Amiyas answer.